# Cast as Datetime not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

OK guys, this is driving me almost insane. I've tried cast, convert, a sub select with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but keep getting this error:

Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

What is wrong with this?

```
insert into somethingtable 
 values ('000000','value','$VAR1 = {};' ,'DummyValue',
         '$VAR1 = {};', Cast('2012-10-13 13:02:08.000' AS datetime),
         '0','1','NULL','NULL')
```

It only seems to care about or complain about the timestamp.

Comment: Does "SELECT Cast('2012-10-13 13:02:08.000' AS datetime)" return an error? The insert statement is really much more information than is needed to troubleshoot the conversion error. Especially without knowing the table definition. On a side note, the insert statement should always define the list of columns. If the ordinal position of the columns changes, your insert will either fail or silently insert values into the wrong columns.

Comment: Yeah, this select statement works fine.

Comment: Timestamp and Datetime are not comparable. I think you will have better assistance, if you publish target table definition in your question. For further information on Timestamp and Datetime uses, please refer to http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/2005/07/30/timestamp-vs-datetime-data-types-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

You'll get errors parsing the yyyy-mm-dd format if you have **SET DATEFORMAT DMY** because SQL Server will try to read it as yyyy-dd-mm instead! From SQL Server 2012 onwards, the dateformat will be ignored specifically for the xxxx-xx-xx format but for now, you're better off using the YYYYMMDD format or for datetime, you can also use **YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS**, e.g. '2012-10-13T13:02:08'.

```
insert into somethingtable 
 values ('000000','value','$VAR1 = {};' ,'DummyValue',
         '$VAR1 = {};', Cast('20121013 13:02:08.000' AS datetime),
         '0','1','NULL','NULL')
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it said the same exact thing. :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ?

`convert(datetime, '2012-10-13 13:02:08.000', 121)`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what worked was using getdate(), instead of Casting the current datetime.